# In R keras, I want to use the predict_generator() function to get a True y value

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, generator, predict

I want to get the True y value using the predict_generator function in R keras, but I do not know how.

But what I can get is the y value predicted by the model.

I want to get the true y value of the test data generated by the generator function.

I need help.

```
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
layer_gru(units = 32, dropout = 0.2, recurrent_dropout = 0.5,
input_shape = list(NULL, dim(data)[[-1]]-1)) %>%
layer_dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid')

model %>% compile(
optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(),
loss = "mse",
metrics = 'accuracy'
)  

history <- model %>% fit(
train_gen,
steps_per_epoch = 80,
epoch = 10,
validation_data = val_gen,
validation_steps = val_steps,

)

pred1 <- predict_generator(model, test_gen, steps=test_steps)
write.csv(pred1,"test(delay=48).csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use generate the test data first, and the apply prediction.

```
test_data <- test_gen()
yhat <- predict(
   model,
   test_data[[1]],
   batch_size = batch_size,
   verbose = 0,
   steps = test_steps)

plot(yhat ~ test_data[[2]])
```